# Where is photodiode in the CD/DVD drives?

Tags: phototransistor

Where is photodiode in the CD/DVD drives?
What is his frequency response & sensetivity usuallY?

I am going to try laser data transfer, but finding decent photodiode is my weak point.

Comment: What datarate are you thinking of?

Comment: 10Mbit initially, than I'll see what I can reach. I can do processing on FPGA & fast ADC/DAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the photodiode that is used to read the disk and not about the one for the IR remote control. This diode is buried below the lense of the laser assembly. Not sure if it will work for your intended purpose because it's a four-quadrant diode, i.e. it has four light-sensitive areas that are used to keep the laser in track.

Comment: You mean it's in separate case? There is a metallic laser case, and somewhere there there is also a photodiode? Hmm... Do you have any info on freq response?

Comment: Should be a different case. See here: http://www.repairfaq.org/REPAIR/cdkssp.gif (via Sam Goldwasser's very nice Repair FAQ, http://www.repairfaq.org/REPAIR/F_cdfaqa.html)

Seems like the photo diode in the laser diode's case is just used to regulate the laser's power output.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want a PIN photodiode. The Osram BPW34 may be a good starting point.